# Removing child root nodes in RABL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

I'm trying to render a pretty simple data structure using RABL, but I can't figure out how to remove the child root nodes properly.  Here are my two templates.

First, the collection index template.

```
collection @groups, :object_root => false

attributes :id, :name
child :files do
  extends 'groups/_file'
end
```

And next, the file partial template.

```
object @file

attributes :id
```

Those two templates end up producing the following JSON:

```
[
   {
      "id":"4f57bf67f85544e620000001",
      "name":"Some Group",
      "files":[
         {
            "file":{
               "id":"4f5aa3fef855441009000007"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to find a way to remove the root "file" key inside of the files collection.  Something like:

```
[
   {
      "id":"4f57bf67f85544e620000001",
      "name":"Some Group",
      "files":[
         {
            "id":"4f5aa3fef855441009000007"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

On latest versions of Rabl, you have to set this configuration if you want `include_root_json` to be `false` in all levels.

```
Rabl.configure do |config|
  config.include_json_root = false
  config.include_child_root = false
end
```

Comment: ive been having this same problem also, and i have tried this solution per the wiki and restarted my server a handful of times, all to no avail.

Answer (score 12):

Try replacing:

```
    child :files do
      extends 'groups/_file'
    end
```

with:

```
    node :files do |group|
      group.files.map do |file|
        partial 'groups/_file', object: file, root: false
      end
    end
```

Comment: the one above is more perfect :P

Answer (score 2):

This is the usual way of removing the root json (rather than specifying object_root: false)

config/initializers/rabl_config.rb

```
Rabl.configure do |config|
  config.include_json_root = false
end
```

Does moving that to there (and restarting rails), fix it?

Comment: Well, I'm not really trying to adjust it globally.  I want to default to including the root nodes.

Comment: Love this. I would rather tell it to /include/ the object root rather than excluding it.

Comment: @c00lryguy if you do `include_json_root = false`, how do you tell it to include the root on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: I settled with JSONBuilder so I have no idea, have you tried the selected answer, but flipping the value of `root` given to the partial?

Answer (score 0):

just putting it out there, in case you want to apply it for a specific child:

```
child :files, :object_root => false do
  extends 'groups/_file'
end
```