# Rabl, remove parent element of children

Tags: rabl

could anyone help me get rid of the "item" element within "items

the output should be:
`"list":{ "items":[ { { data1: "test" } , { data2: "test2" } } }`

```
collection @list

child :items => :items do
  attributes :place_id
end

child :items do
  child :place do |place|
    extends 'places/place', object: place
  end
end
```

current output:
`"list":{ "items":[{ "item":{data1: "test"} "item":{ data2: "test2"}}}`

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and this was the solution. You may need to create the file named to configure rabl.
    config/initializers/rabl.config.rb

```
Rabl.configure do |config|
    config.include_json_root = true
    config.include_child_root =  false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, for future users' reference:

Fire up the file `rabl_init.rb`, turn off root by `config.include_json_root = false`, if you still want a root in your collection objects, use something like:

```
collection @orders, :object_root=>"order"
    extends "api/v1/orders/show"
# End of @orders
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a working solution for removing the root elements in child nodes at: [Removing child root nodes in RABL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673136/removing-child-root-nodes-in-rabl)

Setting the `config.include_json_root = false` seems to remove only the first level root of the JSON.