# Rendering child nodes without the node label in rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, rabl

I am using rabl to build and API in Sinatra.
The required JSON des not accept labels in some nodes
Using this Rabl template:

```
object @user
  attributes :profile_photo => :profile_photo, :name => :first_name, :last_name =>       :last_name
  child :addresses do
  attributes :id 
    child :country do
      attributes :name
    end
  end
```

I am getting the following JSON:

```
{
user: {
profile_photo: null,
first_name: "John",
last_name: "Doe",
addresses: [
{
address: {
id: 43,
country: {
name: "Iceland"
}
}
},
{
address: {
id: 44,
country: {
name: "Cambodia"
}
}
},
{
address: {
id: 45,
country: {
name: "North Korea"
}
}
}
]
}
}
```

Want I want to get is:

```
{
user: {
profile_photo: null,
first_name: "John",
last_name: "Doe",
addresses: [
{
{
id: 43,
country: {
name: "Iceland"
}
}
},
{
{
id: 44,
country: {
name: "Cambodia"
}
}
},
{
{
id: 45,
country: {
name: "North Korea"
}
}
}
]
}
}
```

Is there a way to do it in Rabl?

Answer (score 0):

I have to set the Rabl configuration to:

```
Rabl.configure do |config|
  config.include_json_root = false
  config.include_child_root = false
end
```

I got the answer form another Stack overflow thread:

[Removing child root nodes in RABL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673136/removing-child-root-nodes-in-rabl?rq=1)