# Rabl and array of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

I couldn't find a solution so I decided to ask here.
I'm having this array (the construction can be changed if needed):

```
[[{:time=>2014, :amount=>148.24018480434023}, {:time=>2015, :amount=>152.5625744766238}], [{:time=>2014, :amount=>151.06717076828187}, {:time=>2015, :amount=>158.43869963240266}]]
```

In Rabl template I have:

```
collection @array, object_root: false

node :collection do |s|
  s 
end
```

And the response is:

```
[{"collection": [{"time": 2014,"amount": 148.24018480434023},{"time": 2015,"amount": 152.5625744766238}]},{"collection": [{"time": 2014,"amount": 151.06717076828187},{"time": 2015,"amount": 158.43869963240266}]}]
```

However I would like to get rid off the "collection" nodes and get exactly this response:

```
[ [{ time: 2014, amount: 138.92 }, { time: 2015, amount: 142.98 }], [{ time: 2014, amount: 141.57 }, { time: 2015, amount: 148.48 }] ]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get rid of the root try

```
#  config/initializers/rabl_init.rb
Rabl.configure do |config|
  config.include_json_root = false
  config.include_child_root = false
end
```

https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/4

Similar: [Removing child root nodes in RABL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673136/removing-child-root-nodes-in-rabl?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but for posterity sake. The simplest approach is to remove the :collection on the node call. So for your example it would be as below

```
collection @array, object_root: false

node do |s|
  s 
end
```